# Make scrollable table

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdbc, jlist

I'm making this program in Java in which I sell stuff to those connected via socket.  I'm loading the products and prices via JDBC just fine, but I want to display the product with the price next to it in a scrollable table. Right now I just have this JList in which I load the names of the products:

Please, click the link below to understand the question.

[image]

What elements should I use and how to accomplish what I'm needing?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) maybe?

Comment: Check out [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), (I'm sure some else has already linked root, I just labelled it more clearly ;)) and just for comparison, [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `JTable` with `JScrollPane`

**Updated** reference example links:

[this reference example](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-create-a-scrollable-jtable-component/) and [and this](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-jtable) might help you

Comment: @Granola pleasure to help you

Comment: Unfortunately that link is no longer available.

Comment: @Iain thanks for notifying. Updated with another example url

Comment: @exexzian Usually, we should try to include *absolutely necessary code* in the answer itself to avoid 'dead link' issues.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can accomplish this with a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) component in swing .

Answer (score 3):

Use JTable with JScrollPane in it for scrolling  from top to down or from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

You need a JTable in a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) and [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

**Sample Code:**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class ProductTableExample {

    public static void main( String[] str ) {
        String[] colName = new String[] { "Product Name" ,"Price" };
        Object[][] products = new Object[][] { 
                { "Galleta" ,"$80" },
                { "Malta" ,"$40" },
                { "Nestea" ,"$120" },
                { "Tolta" ,"$140" } 
            };

        JTable table = new JTable( products, colName );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Simple Table Example" );

        // create scroll pane for wrapping the table and add
        // it to the frame
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );       
    }

}
```